# how do I automatically save the s3 bucket names in glue pyspark script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

My problem now is I have tons of JSON files in a S3 bucket (which contains several sub buckets).
I want to explode it and save to a new flat file with one of the column telling me which sub bucket the records were originally from.
How do I do it in SQL to automatically get that information? THanks!!
I am using glue pyspark , btw.

Comment: You can use `input_file_name()`column. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349181/import-pyspark-dataframe-from-multiple-s3-buckets-with-a-column-denoting-which?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: @blackbishop THANK YOU!! exactly what I needed. Another question..how do I get the bucket name of the sub bucket too? For example, my main bucket has 10 buckets (called month), and each bucket has a few buckets (called Day), then have sub buckets under Day (called Hour)... How can i grab all the names (like "month/Day/Hour" format?

Comment: I think I figured it out - getItem(0), getItem(1), getItem(2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from comments -> You can use input_file_name()column